Trying to prove: that for every line, there exists at least one point not on it
I am trying to prove the proposition above with the Incidence Axioms. Specifically, I want to use the third axiom, which states, 'There exist at least three non-collinear points.' However, I want to avoid false proofs, such as the following: 'By Incidence Axiom 3, there are three points A, B, and C such that no line is incident to all of them. Let l be the line containing points A and B. Then, according to the axiom, point C cannot lie on line l.' Can someone explain why this proof is incorrect? I'll put my attempts below, and please let me know if it is also a flawed proof or if there's anything that needs to be modified.
First attempt:
Consider an arbitrary line l.
By Incidence Axiom 3, we know that there exist three distinct points A, B, and C that are not collinear.
Suppose, for the sake of contradiction, that every point lies on line l.
Without loss of generality, assume that A does not lie on l with points B and C on the line.
Now consider the line AB. Since A does not lie on l, the line AB intersects with the point B.
The line AB is unique and not parallel to l and A is unique to B; therefore, A isn't on l.
But this contradicts the assumption that every point lies on line l.
Therefore, our initial assumption is false, and there must be at least one point not lying on line l.
Hence, the proposition holds true.
Second attempt: I wanted to take a slightly different approach, is this the same as my first attempt? Starting with the assumption that every line contains all points (i.e., every point lies on some line), we invoke Incidence Axiom 3, which states that there exist three distinct points not collinear. Let’s denote these points as A, B, and C. Without loss of generality, we assume that two points on line l are B and C. Now consider any arbitrary point A. Since B and C lie on l, A must also be on l according to our assumption. However, this contradicts Incidence Axiom 3, which requires the existence of three non-collinear points. Therefore, A cannot be collinear with B and C, implying that there exists a point not lying on line l. Consequently, we’ve demonstrated that for every line, there exists a point not on it.

In "first attempt", you assume $A$ is not on $l$, and then deduce that $A$ is not on $l$, so you've assumed what you're trying to prove.

Does the second attempt remedy that? Since I'm only assuming that there exists an A, but prove that A can't be on l?

In the second attempt, line $l$ is introduced in a way that does not appear to allow you to say that what you show about $l$ is also true of every line. I think you forgot that you still had an assumption to contradict.

I wasn't quite sure how to introduce the line l, but since it was in the hypothesis I wanted to start with that first and construct the points using the axiom. The contradiction arrives from the fact that given the line and the axiom, the points can't lie on the line the way the axiom would suggest.

Using the fact that there are three non-collinear points, and letting $l$ be the line determined by two of those points, you have proved that there is one line (namely, $l$) for which a point exists that is not on that line. What about other lines?

The proof seems to be way over-complicated, anyway.
